# Are the words "burden" and "weight" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use the word "weight" instead of "burden" in the phrases bellow? Do they have the same meaning when used in this context?

Must be such a heavy **burden / weight** for them to carry so much hate around all the time!

Two older sisters can be such a heavy **burden / weight** for a small boy to bear.

In tears, she cried: “I never meant to be such a heavy **burden /weight** for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burden is better in these cases.  We often use "burden" metaphorically.  Using "weight" could be read literally (two sisters are a heavy weight, if they are sitting on your back.)